# progress bar on videoview android

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-videoview

HI 
i am developing video streaming application and i need to make a progress bar on my application (not a progress dialog) i tried implementing it i put it on the xml file and set it to invisible on the onprepared method but the problem is that the progress bar is placed on top of the video which makes the video size small 
i need to make the video fill parent and the progress bar also like the youtube application 
how can i do that ?

also i'm online streaming so how can i display the buffering percentage when the video is stopped for delay

another point is i want the progress bar to disappear when the alert of this video canot be played now ,, but i don't know where in the code i should disappear the progress bar ? when this alert appears ?

Comment: You can check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802645/in-android-how-to-get-the-progress-time-of-the-video-played-under-videoview)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how YouTube does their menu, but you could try a [SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html) and nest your `ProgressBar` in that.

Answer (score -2):

look at this code, this might help you.
This code also include necessary comments , where ever needed.

```
  public void videoPlayer(String path, String fileName, boolean autoplay){

      //get current window information, and set format, set it up differently, if you need some special effects

      getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

      //the VideoView will hold the video

      VideoView videoHolder = new VideoView(this);

      //MediaController is the ui control howering above the video (just like in the default youtube player).

      videoHolder.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));

      //assing a video file to the video holder

      videoHolder.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path+"/"+fileName));

      //get focus, before playing the video.

      videoHolder.requestFocus();

      if(autoplay){

          videoHolder.start();

      }

   }
```

Thanks...

Comment: That does not answer the question!