# Get the progress time of the video played under videoview?

Tags: android

I need to get the progress time of the video that is played in "VideoView"(ie the time shown in the left hand side in progress bar).

Any help will really be appreciated.
 Thanks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can get the Duration of the Video by `mVideoView.getDuration()`, set the Progress bar to 0 initially and then get the currentProgress of Video by `mVideoView.getCurrentPosition();` and increase the Progress Bar status based on the CurrentProgress of Video in Percentage(%) by `(current * 100 / duration)`. I tried it out using `AsyncTask` checkout this complete Example.

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<VideoView  android:id="@+id/my_Video_View"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />

    <ProgressBar android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="10dp"
  android:id="@+id/Progressbar"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**VideoPlayActivity.java**

```
public class VideoPlayActivity extends Activity {

    ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    VideoView mVideoView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        String filename = "/hr.3gp";

        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.Progressbar);
        mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
        mProgressBar.setMax(100);

        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.my_Video_View);
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path+filename));
        new MyAsync().execute();
    }

    private class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>
    {
        int duration = 0;
        int current = 0;
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            mVideoView.start();
            mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    duration = mVideoView.getDuration();
                }
            });

            do {
                current = mVideoView.getCurrentPosition();
                System.out.println("duration - " + duration + " current- "
                        + current);
                try {
                    publishProgress((int) (current * 100 / duration));
                    if(mProgressBar.getProgress() >= 100){
                        break;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            } while (mProgressBar.getProgress() <= 100);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            System.out.println(values[0]);
            mProgressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you really call `mVideoView.start();` in `doInBackground`? no wrongUiThread exception?

Comment: hi Lalit. What happens if the user exits the VideoView or closes it? How can prevent this AsyncTask from executing infinitely?

Comment: @android-user you can abviously call `cancel()` method on your AsyncTask

Comment: method `setOnPreparedListener`must be called from the UI thread.

Comment: All your background task code should be called from UI thread

Comment: I'm getting this error: Method getCurrentPosition must be called from the UI thread, currently inferred thread is worker thread. Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 9):

You can use Thread for this purpose like below:

```
videoView.start();
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            running = true;
            final int duration = videoView.getDuration();

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {  
                    do{                         
                        textView.post(new Runnable() {
                         public void run() {
                            int time = (duration - videoView.getCurrentPosition())/1000;
                            textView.setText(time+"");
                         }
                        });
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {                                      
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if(!running) break;
                    }
                    while(videoView.getCurrentPosition()<duration);
                }
            }).start();                     
        }
    });
```

Comment: this results in leak in the textview

Comment: @isudansh don't worry about memory leaks, just forget

Answer (score 6):

You can use `getCurrentPosition()` and `getDuration()`to calculate the progress.

Comment: but, when to call those methods?, as I need to track it every second.

Comment: @mr-narendra , You can refer to answers from Nolesh and Aleksey Timoshchenko above with timer or thread sleep set to 1000 ms.

Comment: I achieved that with help of the `handler`.

Answer (score 5):

I accomplished it such way

```
private void playVideo() {
    setViewNotVisibility();

    final String videoSource = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + File.separator + R.raw.moviiegood;
    videoView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoSource));
    videoView.setMediaController(null);
    videoView.setOnCompletionListener(myVideoViewCompletionListener);
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                            startVideo();
                                            setDuration();
                                            timerCounter();
                                        }
                                    }

    );
}

private Timer timer;
private void timerCounter(){
    timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    updateUI();
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(task, 0, 1000);
}

private int duration = 0;

private void setDuration(){
    duration = videoView.getDuration();
}

private void updateUI(){
    if (pbVideoView.getProgress() >= 100) {
        timer.cancel();
    }
    int current = videoView.getCurrentPosition();
    int progress = current * 100 / duration;
    pbVideoView.setProgress(progress);
}
```

If you have a questions feel free to ask