# Streaming media length

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer, live-streaming

I want to play media file (mp3) from url. and also I want to get the length of that mp3 file.
I am successful in playing file but I also want to display SeekBar. For that I need to know the length of media file in seconds.

How can I achieve that ?

I found one way but using that I don't think it gave me length in seconds.

```
 URLConnection cn = new URL(mediaUrl).openConnection();
 cn.connect();
 int length =  cn.getContentLength();
```

I think it returns bytes. So Can I convert it into seconds ?
Or any one know other way ?

Comment: Try same way as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802645/in-android-how-to-get-the-progress-time-of-the-video-played-under-videoview/7803166#7803166) it is done for Video.

Comment: @LalitPoptani thanks for your reply but in that I dont think that video is playing from url. so when I try getDuration() method it gave me the buffered duration but when it buffered full its value is changed. like first 400,567,1234,and at last 4000. so my Seekbar is fluctuating...I hope you understand .

Answer (score 1):

Check out the getHeaderFields() method and then check if there is a response header containing the length. If not you can get the content out, read the mp3 meta data from the stream and figure out the kbps. Once you have that, u can get the length in time using the length in bytes.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is what is needed to pull any data from a URL.

You may in fact be pulling an MP3 file from this `url` but the `getContentLength()` you are calling is acting upon the `URLConnection` object - what it returns is the **size** of the file you are downloading (bytes, kilobytes, megabytes).

If you want to check for the play time of the MP3 you're going to have to cooerse the data into a valid media object which should then have it's own accessors such as `getDuration()`.

Answer (score 0):

Once your media streaming has begun, you can use the `mediaplayer.getDuration` to get the total duration of the media file. this value can then be used within a runnable to regularly update your seekbar.

Comment: mediaplayer.getDuration returns me only how much is buffered not total duration .... :(