# Video Tracking time in android

Tags: android, video, time, tracking

I have video view it playing videos correctly but i want know video starting time and end time because i want send this tracking time to my server how can i do this programmatically in android.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802645/in-android-how-to-get-the-progress-time-of-the-video-played-under-videoview

Comment: Thanks Akash i got exactly what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is same as this try this - [Get the progress time of the video played under videoview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802645/in-android-how-to-get-the-progress-time-of-the-video-played-under-videoview)

This will help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the current time by videoview.getCurrentTime() and videoview.getduration() Method.
This can help you.