# Android MediaPlayer getCurrentPosition() causes audio stutter

Tags: android, audio, media-player

I'm using a SeekBar to display the progress of an audio file and for seeking to a certain time. For updating I use a Runnable which calls getCurrentPosition() on a MediaPlayer every second or so. Every time that happens there is a small amount of lag in the audio. Since I call it often, I get very noticeable stuttering while playing something. If it's relevant, I'm using setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC) and the file format is mp4 whith AAC audio (no video) and I'm using Android 2.3.4. Is there a way to get good audio with getCurrentPosition(), or do I have to implement my own progress calculations?

The Runnable:

```
private Runnable mUpdateTask = new Runnable(){

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mSeekBar.setProgress((int) (mPlayer.getCurrentPosition() * 100 / mArrayAdapter.getRecording(mPlayingId).mDuration));
        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTask, 999);
    }
};
```

Comment: I had done that for VideoView you can check it out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802645/in-android-how-to-get-the-progress-time-of-the-video-played-under-videoview/7803166#7803166)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I use this method to caluclate progress'

```
public static int getProgressPercentage(long currentDuration,
            long totalDuration) {
        Double percentage = (double) 0;

        long currentSeconds = (int) (currentDuration / 1000);
        long totalSeconds = (int) (totalDuration / 1000);

        // calculating percentage
        percentage = (((double) currentSeconds) / totalSeconds) * 100;

        // return percentage
        return percentage.intValue();
    }
```

Note: mPlayer.getCurrentPosition() is not accurate. There are some bugs reported. I had problem that current position was higher than totalDuration.

Comment: I've implemented something similar, but a bit more complicated since i have pausing and seeking.

Comment: Can you please tell me what has to be passed to the method? ie. how to get currentDuration?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem or something similar.

When I've used `mMediapPlayer.getCurrentPosition()` in a TimerTask to update the SeekBar, I heard sound problems like echo but actually the problem wasn't there..

The issue is that I've also used SeekBar `OnSeekBarChangeListener` for manual seek but what happened is that update the seekBar from the TimerTask also triggered the listener, which did `mp.seekTo(progress)` and this, caused the mp to return back to that position again..

I've fixed it by using the `fromUser` argument as suggested here to do seek only if the seekBar changed manually.

Here is my sample code:

The TimerTask:

```
public void initializeTimerTask() {

    mTimerTask = new TimerTask() {

        public void run() {

            int progress = mp.getCurrentPosition()/1000;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mSeekBar.setProgress(progress);
                    tvDuration.setText(DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(progress));
                }
            });

        }
    };
}
```

Listener:

```
 mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if(mp != null && fromUser){
                mp.seekTo(progress * 1000);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: my issue exactly.. it was driving me crazy. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like this:

```
private Runnable mUpdateTask = new Runnable(){

    @Override
    public void run() 
  {
        mSeekBar.setProgress(mMediapPlayer.getCurrentPosition());       
        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTask, 999);
    }
};
```

you can also apply seek bar progress change listener as follow:

```
mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
            {               
                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) 
                {               
                }
                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
                {                   
                }
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) 
                {
                    if (fromUser) 
                    {
                        int secProgress = seekBar.getSecondaryProgress();
                                if (secProgress> progress) 
                                {
                                    mMediapPlayer.seekTo(progress);
                                } 
                                else
                                {   
                                    seekBar.setProgress(mSeekBar.getProgress());
                                }
                    }

                }               
            });
            mMediapPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() 
            {

                    @Override
                    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) 
                    {
                        mSeekBar.setSecondaryProgress((mSeekBar.getMax()/100)*percent);

                    }
                });
```