# Video view and date and time in android

Tags: android, date, time, android-videoview

I have a module in my application which displays the start time and the end time of the video.

I have create a videoview and these times are shown on the video view. This is working very well.

Now, Is it possible that when I run this video on a laptop/desktop, it shows me the start time and the end time along with the video? Is it possible through any jar file or something.

This is something that I want to know for my knowledge. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly the link you are looking for:
[Get the progress time of the video played under videoview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802645/in-android-how-to-get-the-progress-time-of-the-video-played-under-videoview)

It tells you how to display time on the video progress bar.

Comment: No... this is not wht I am looking for. My start time is not 00:00:00. It is the current time i.e., say 11:28:00 to the end time of the video say, 11:30:00. Now I have got this working on the video. When I play the video in my player. It very well shows this perfectly.

Comment: But is it possible to show this same when I copy the video from phone onto the desktop/laptop?

Comment: how are you going to run the video on desktop/laptop?

Comment: simply copy it on the desktop/laptop and run it in any media player. I am just asking whether this is possible to show the start time and the end time by any means

Comment: What you are asking here then has nothing to do with android. You can build a code for the videoview and put in functionality but on a desktop/laptop, the media player is already there which you cannot reprogram.