# How can I stop a video after 30 seconds

Tags: android, timer, media-player

I want to have a video in my app that has a free 30 seconds preview but instead of having two separate videos one full and one a 30 sec section how can I simply stop the video after 30 seconds of playing

Here is the block of code I use to play audios or videos

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    /** REMOVE TITLE **/
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.moveplay);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);

    final VideoView audioView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
    final MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(audioView);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String pathfile = extras.getString("key");
    Log.v("key = ",pathfile);

    Uri audio = Uri.parse(pathfile);
    audioView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    audioView.setVideoURI(audio);
    audioView.start();
```

I have another section of my app that determines whether to play from the SD card or stream it and that all works fine.

I would simply like to set a flag so either the first 30 secs of the vid plays or the entire vid plays.

I know the controller appears when I tap the screen and I see the counter i just need to stop it when the current position reaches 30 that way I save on resources with just a single vid for both

Thanks
Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step #1: Use `postDelayed()` or something to get control every second or so.

Step #2: Check `getCurrentPosition()` and see if it is near your 30s marker point. If so then stop the video view.
The code for determining the progressof the video played is given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802645/in-android-how-to-get-the-progress-time-of-the-video-played-under-videoview) link.