# Callback on VideoView progress

Tags: android, listener, android-videoview

I'm looking for a way to get a callback when a `VideoView` is playing, indicating the video progress. Something like described [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=145), but for a `VideoView`. Polling the current progress every fixed duration seems a bad solution…

Is there any listener existing for this that I missed?

Comment: no, you didnt miss anything. whats wrong with polling?

Comment: Well, it doesn't feel logical, a component should notify others about its status changes, not the opposite...

Comment: See my solution on the similar question: [Get the progress time of the video played under videoview?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33370149/925504)

Comment: @Nolesh well that's pretty much the same as the accepted answer for nearly two years now ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a thread to get the progress.

```
mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {     
        Log.i(TAG, "::run: getCurrentPosition = " + mVideoView.getCurrentPosition());       
        if(mVideoView.isPlaying()){
            mHandler1.postDelayed(this, 250);                   
        }
    }
};
mHandler1.post(mRunnable);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Runnable onEverySecond=new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if(seekbar != null) {
                    seekbar.setProgress(mPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                }
                if(mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    System.out.println("inside runnable :::::: is playing  ");
                    seekbar.postDelayed(onEverySecond, 10);
                }
            }
        };
                seekbar.postDelayed(onEverySecond, 10);
```