# Let user play video by doing tap on it

Tags: android, video

I am listing videos and showing selected one in another activity and it started playing automatically.

But my motto to allow user tap on it to play, like we see in many mobile apps.

secondly, not showing duration and progress

**activity_single_contact.xml:-**

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:padding="10dp">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**SingleContactActivity.java:-**

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_contact);

    // getting intent data
    Intent in = getIntent();
    String mobile = in.getStringExtra(TAG_URL);

    Uri uri=Uri.parse(mobile);
    VideoView video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    video.setVideoURI(uri);
    video.start();
    }
```

and also ***how to show total duration of video and progress duration with seek bar***, like we normally see in video apps ?

**How to control** on, *Tap to Play* and *Tap to Pause*, again like other Video Apps !!!!

Comment: Well to start the video you would have to put the video.start(); call in a touch event, like on a button event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are directly starting video in your onCreate fucntion. You can write image buttons in your layout. And on click of those buttons you can write video start code.

Example:

**VideoPlayerActivity.java**

```
public class VideoPlayerActivity extends Activity {

    private boolean mResumed = false;
    private boolean mFocused = false;
    private boolean mControlResumed = false;
    private VideoView videoView = null;
    private int stopPosition = 0;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_TransparentVideo);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);

        setContentView(R.layout.video_view);

        videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
        MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);        
        Uri uri=Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.slow);        
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);        
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mResumed = false;
        if (mControlResumed) {
            if (null != videoView)
                videoView.pause();
            stopPosition = videoView.getCurrentPosition();
            mControlResumed = false;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mResumed = true;
        if (mFocused && mResumed && !mControlResumed) {
            if(null != videoView) {
                //videoView.resume();
                videoView.seekTo(stopPosition);
                videoView.start();
            }
            mControlResumed = true;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        mFocused = hasFocus;
        if (mFocused && mResumed && !mControlResumed) {
            if (null != videoView) {
                //videoView.resume();
                videoView.seekTo(stopPosition);
                videoView.start();
            }
            mControlResumed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Now call this activity from your class:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(mContext, VideoPlayerActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: is there any way to use all controllers like play, pause, back, forward, resume, total duration, progress bar and more...because its very difficult to implement custom widgets for everything

Comment: By default you get all these features it you play the video using VideoView. You will get 3 buttons and a progressbar. 1) Play/Pause button. 2) Back button 3) Forward button. Resume works by default in android. To the right of progressbar you can see total duration. While the video is playing, just tap on screen once and you will see all these controls.

Comment: as you can see i am using VideoView, so why i am not getting these controls?

Comment: I have provided you an example. You need to add MediaController as well.

Answer (score 1):

Put your video.Start in a touch event like on a button or something and maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802645/get-the-progress-time-of-the-video-played-under-videoview) link will help you for duration