# How to check a variable in background to do something when it reaches to a value?

Tags: android, background

I have a simple VideoView that plays a video:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final VideoView videoView=findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.video));
        MediaController mediaController=new MediaController(this);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.start();

        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }
}
```

By using `videoView.getCurrentPosition()`, I can get the current elapsed milliseconds of the playing video. Now, I need to **continuously** check this value in background, and when it reaches to some (for example 10000), do something (updating the TextView's text).

It's important for me to do this is background so that doesn't disturb the video playback.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the `MediaController`'s `SeekBar` events, by overriding its 3 methods, of course you' re interested in 1 of them `onProgressChanged()`:

```
    final VideoView videoView=findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.video));
    final MediaController mediaController=new MediaController(this);
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);


    final TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText("0");

    int topContainerId = getResources().getIdentifier("mediacontroller_progress","id", "android");
    final SeekBar seekbar = (SeekBar) mediaController.findViewById(topContainerId);

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            int currentValue = Integer.parseInt(textView.getText().toString());
            int newValue = progress / 1000;
            if (newValue != currentValue) {
                textView.setText(String.valueOf(newValue));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });

    videoView.start();
```

Comment: Thank you @mTak for your help. I exactly did what you said but when running my project, I get this error in logcat:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.arantik.test7/com.example.arantik.test7.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.SeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(android.widget.SeekBar$OnSeekBarChangeListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: Check my edited code, there must be some problem with the id of the seekbar

Comment: Thank you. this is an activity.

Comment: When I define a SeekBar in activity_main.xml , and then use "SeekBar seekBar=findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);" the problem is solved, but this way, NO change will occur in TextView.

Comment: No this seekbar is the MediaController's seekbar. Don't define a new one

Comment: I found this link, that might give you an alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802645/get-the-progress-time-of-the-video-played-under-videoview

Comment: Yes I've seen this link before. thank you for your help.